# Shape estimation in truncated Pareto in R

Tags: r, estimation, fitdistrplus, vgam

```
library(VGAM)
library(fitdistrplus)

fitdist(u_NI$k_u, 'truncpareto',
         start = list(lower=1,
                      upper=42016,
                      shape=1)) -> fit.k_u
```

`length(u_NI$k_u) = 637594`

I got this error:

```
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
Error in fitdist(u_NI$k_u, "truncpareto", start = list(lower = 1, upper = 42016,  : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In fitdist(u_NI$k_u, "truncpareto", start = list(lower = 1, upper = 42016,  :
  The dtruncpareto function should return a zero-length vector when input has length zero
2: In fitdist(u_NI$k_u, "truncpareto", start = list(lower = 1, upper = 42016,  :
  The ptruncpareto function should return a zero-length vector when input has length zero
```

Is the problem in the excessive size of the dataset or in the start parameters?

REPRODUCIBILE EXAMPLE:

```
library(VGAM)
library(fitdistrplus)

rtruncpareto(100,1,100,1.5) -> a
fitdist(a, "truncpareto",
        start = list(lower=1,
                     upper=100,
                     shape=1.5))
```

This is not going to work, and I don't understand why.

It seems it has a problem here:

`argument 'lower' must be positive`

Comment: Maybe following the [documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/VGAM/html/paretoff.html) and last example of package VGAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is a more general issue, i.e. that for a truncated distribution the MLE of the boundary parameter(s) is in general equal to the *observed* min/max of the data set. So you should always be able to do at least as well by setting the values of the lower/upper bounds equal to the min/max (based on my experience trying this they have to be *slightly* below/above the observed bounds). (I also found I had to set `lower = 0` to stop the algorithm from trying negative values of the shape parameter.)

```r
library(VGAM); library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(101)
rtruncpareto(100,1,100,1.5) -> a
eps <- 1e-8
fitdist(a, "truncpareto",
        start = list(shape=1.5),
        fix.arg = list(lower = min(a) - eps, upper = max(a) + eps),
        lower = 0)
Parameters:
      estimate Std. Error
shape 1.349885  0.1554436
Fixed parameters:
          value
lower  1.006844
upper 25.906577
```

An alternative to `fitdist` would be `bbmle`:

```r
library(bbmle)
m1 <- mle2(a ~ dtruncpareto(lower = min(a) - eps,
                            upper = max(a) + eps,
                            shape = exp(lshape)),
           start = list(lshape = 0),
           data = data.frame(a),
         method = "BFGS")
exp(coef(m1))   
  lshape 
1.349884
```

`bbmle` is a little bit more flexible and allows you to fit the shape parameter on the log scale, which is generally more robust (and makes the standard deviation estimates more useful). Using `method = "BFGS"` here because the default Nelder-Mead algorithm works poorly for 1-dimensional optimization; could also use `method = "Brent"` (which would be more efficient and robust) but would then need to provide explicit lower and upper bounds for the `lshape` parameter.

Comment: When I follow your code with bbmle, it works.
When I plug my data instead of toy data, this is the error:

Error in dtruncpareto(x = c(2273L, 2148L, 1838L, 1702L, 1672L, 1559L,  : 
  argument 'shape' must be positive

This happens also when I set start = list(shape = 1.5)

Comment: What do you see if you add `trace=TRUE` to the `mle2()` call?

Comment: 1.5 303055.6 
1.501 303447.8 
1.499 302664.4 
Error in dtruncpareto(x = c(2273L, 2148L, 1838L, 1702L, 1672L, 1559L,  : 
  argument 'shape' must be positive

It seems that it starts, than it fails.

Comment: how big is your data set? Can you post it or post a link to it? The only thing I can think of is that `lshape` is going strongly negative so that `lshape` underflows to 0 (and that the tracing is only happening *after* the likelihood evaluation, so we're not seeing when it fails). What happens if you try `shape = 1e-8 + exp(lshape)` instead of `shape = exp(lshape)` ?

Comment: Right now I cannot share the database; I could extract just the vector later.
When I add `1e-8` the algorithm converges into `exp(1.1) = 2,77`; when I apply `shape = lshape`, it converges into `2.77`. This result it's a bit off of my "prior", given results obtained with `mge`.

Comment: Not sure what "when I apply `shape = lshape` means ... not surprising that two different objective functions (MLE vs MGE ['maximum goodness of fit', whatever that is precisely, I'm not sure]) don't give the same answer, not sure how to judge how different they "should" be, especially without seeing the data ...

Comment: However, I filtered `k_u > x`, with `x` being integers and I checked that the `alpha` is coherent with `mge` for all integers. The shift is only for `x = 0`, when `k_u` includes `k_u == 1`, which leads me to think that the vector is a truncated pareto with 1-inflation, and the 1-inflation is responsible for the mis-estimation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure, but this might be what your after.

```r
library(fitdistrplus)
library(VGAM)
library(ggplot2)

u_NI <- data.frame("k_u" = rtruncpareto(10000,
                                        lower = 1,
                                        upper = 100,
                                        shape = 1.5))

fit <- vglm(k_u ~ 1,
            truncpareto(lower=1, upper=max(u_NI$k_u) + 1),
            data = u_NI,
            trace = TRUE)

x <- seq(1, max(u_NI$k_u), length.out = 10000)
y <- dtruncpareto(x, shape = fit@coefficients[["(Intercept)"]],
                  lower=fit@extra$lower,
                  upper=fit@extra$upper)
pareto <- cbind.data.frame(x, y)

ggplot()+
  geom_density(data = u_NI, aes(k_u))+
  geom_line(data = pareto, aes(x = x, y = y, color = "truncpareto"),linetype = 5, size = 1.3)+
  theme(legend.position = c(.95, .95),
        legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

##########################
Edit:

```r
# fix lower and upper boundary, estimate may still fail, depending on     the start value of shape
fitdist(u_NI$k_u, 'truncpareto',
        method = "mle",
        start = list(shape=1),
        fix.arg=list(lower=1, upper=max(u_NI$k_u) + 0.01),
        control=list(trace=1, REPORT=1)) -> fit.k_u

# use different method to estimate parameter, mge seems to work
fitdist(u_NI$k_u, 'truncpareto',
        method = "mge",
        start = list(shape=1,
                     lower=1,
                     upper=max(u_NI$k_u) + 1),
        control=list(trace=1, REPORT=1)) -> fit.k_u
```

The errors that remain refer to this:

```r
> pnorm(numeric(), 1,10)
numeric(0)
> ptruncpareto(numeric(), 1,10,5)
[1] NA
```

####### Edit2:
I think i found the original error and its a bit confusing. However, there is also a lower parameter for the mle, that is separate from the lower parameter of the distribution. It should restrain parameter estimates to >= 0. Hence, this should work, however it takes a good while, even for just 10,000 values:

```r
fitdist(u_NI$k_u, 'truncpareto',
        method = "mle",
        start = list(shape=1,
                     lower=1,
                     upper=max(u_NI$k_u) +1 ),
        control=list(trace=1, REPORT=1),
        lower = 0) -> fit.k_u
```

Comment: This is a visual representation of the fit, but I just want the shape estimate, given lower and upper bounds. In the fit object I can find values for the estimates of lower and upper bounds, and then a value called "coefficient". But it is reported as Intercept. Even in the plot, shape refers to is as the Intercept. It is also noteworthy different from the parameter...

Comment: When I apply your code to my data, this is the error:

`Error in eval(slot(family, "initialize")) : 
  the value of argument 'lower' is too high (requires '0 < lower < min(y)')`

Comment: what would be the minimum value in your data?

Comment: 1, just as in the toy data. Curiously, with `k_u+1` it converges to estimates; even if again, these are not unbiased.

Comment: I can only add that by other numerical means, I believe that the data in `k_u` are coherent with the hypothesis that the shape parameter for `k_u` is 1.7, given a upper bound = 42016.

Comment: from what I can tell, the error stems from incompatible parameter estimates of mle, e.g. negative lower boundaries or shape estimates. I have found two possibilities to circumvent them and edited my original answer.